# How to solve Xcode's crash?

Tags: macos, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode so it should behave normally but it keep open up with my last project and crash. No matter how many times i uninstall and reinstall. Is there a fix for this?? Please help i need to get this thing fix soon.
At the time of crash it says internal logic error. I read somewhere that i should restart my system after installing the new Xcode of it will crash again but as it gets installed it reopen automatically.

Thanks,

Comment: If you haven't already, please [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: It sounds like it's your project that has gotten corrupted somehow. Have you tried to move the project files away, so that Xcode can't open it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the optimal solution [but I have talked to other people who have had problems like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343866/xcode-4-2-1-crashes-on-lion-10-7-2-on-launch/8351124#8351124) and the solution they ended up doing was to create a new user on the Macintosh where they were having trouble and then Xcode worked perfectly fine.

Try that and see if you have any good luck.

I suspect there's some cached settings that aren't being cleared out with uninstalls & reinstalls.